# Is there a way to make a UIView round?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I don't mean make it LOOK round. I know about `cornerRadius` and `masksToBounds`. When you use those, the view is really just a rectangle with the corners hidden. I need a view that is literally a circle. Is this possible?

Comment: No. But why would you need that?

Comment: I've basically got a few circular views that are acting as bouncy balls bouncing against each other. The problem is that the (invisible) corners are causing the balls to bounce.

Comment: I think you should draw those objects with graphics and not use UIView. Is there a reason why you want to use UIView?

Comment: You probably want to use SpriteKit. You can use `SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 123)` to create a circular shape, and detect collisions with the edge of the circle using the `didBeginContact(_:)` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are after this as you only want to allow touch events *inside* the circle, not on the rect edges... this is done by overriding the `pointInside` UIView method, to only accept points within a defined path.

This can be done by storing the edge of your circle (or really any `UIBezierPath`) then checking if that path contains the given point:

```
@interface CircleView : UIView

@propery (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *edgePath; // init this with your path details

@end

@implementation CircleView

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return [edgePath containsPoint:point];
}

@end
```

Comment: The OP is using Swift, BTW. Also, this logic is effectively already implemented in `SKShapeNode`. That said, this is a more minimal solution that could work effectively.